# How to make Firefox ignore the X-XSS-Protection response header?

Tags: web-browser, xss, chrome, firefox

I have two questions:

1. How can I make Firefox ignore the `X-XSS-Protection` header? I have a website which sends an `X-XSS-Protection: 1` header and I want my Firefox to ignore that header, because it destroys my reflected XSS tests.
   I know Chrome has a directive `--disable-xss-auditor` to ignore it but I can't find anywhere how to do the same in Firefox.
2. How to disable XSS protection from web browser itself (Firefox + Chrome). I'm now not saying about header from a server, but how to disable built into web browser protection against reflected XSS?

Comment: AFAIK firefox doesn't have an xss filter like Chrome and IE do and ignores that header. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=528661 .

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan that would explain why I couldn't find answer to 'how to disable it'. I've seen that bug ticket and a few other related to this but some time left since last update so thought it was introduced. Do you know the answer for 2) ?

Comment: Assuming you're using Burp Suite (like everybody does), you should use a response rewrite rule to convert that header to a `0` (and possibly add it if not present). Works with all browsers and doesn't require using a different browser configuration when you want to test something (aside from running traffic through the proxy).

Comment: 1. If you are allowed to use Addon you can use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/ 2. For Firefox you can try `Open Firefox -> type "about:config" in the address bar -> Search "browser.urlbar.filter.javascript" -> Select "False"`